# Using backticks in react-table hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

Hi guys I am having issues when i use `backticks` inside the hooks section of `useTable`

For example, in the code below me declaring `randomVarBT` gives me an error.

```
    (hooks) => {
      hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => [
        ...columns,
        {
          id: 'view',
          groupByBoundary: true,
          Header: () => (
            <div>
              View
            </div>
          ),
          Cell: ({ row }) => {
            const randomVarBT = `x`;
            return (
              <Button myval={randomVarBT} />
            );
          },
        },
      ]);
    },
```

I get the following error. If I use `""` instead of backticks The below error doesn't come.

> Cannot read property 'value' of null
> Occurred while linting /home/LOCATION_TO_FILE/Filename.js:87

Comment: What are you using to compile your code? is this create-react-app or something? interchanging backticks and regular quotes definitely shouldn't be causing any errors, I'm suspicious some other code being left out that would trigger this. does your actual code use variables in your template `${var}` ?

Comment: I am using create-react-app. The back tick issue doesn't exist in other places. It event works normally when i make the connection using template strings inside a component which is rendered by the hooks, but when I pass props with backticks/template strings I get that error.

Comment: are you able to reproduce this in something like codesandbox?